# ReactRouter does not render anything

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browserify

I use this jsx script to render the app component in my index.html file.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Router = require ('react-router').Router;
var Route = require ('react-router').Route;
var IndexRoute = require ('react-router').IndexRoute;
var browserHistory = require ('react-router').hashHistory;

require('./css/style.css');

var LandingComponent = require('./components/landing.jsx');
var LoginComponent = require('./components/login.jsx');
var SignupComponent = require('./components/signup.jsx');
var HomeComponent = require('./components/home.jsx');

console.log("this is app.js");

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path={'/'} component={LoginComponent}></Route>
                <Route path={'/signup'} component={SignupComponent}></Route>
                <Route path={'/home'} component={HomeComponent}></Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Render rendering the components directly like

```
ReactDOM.render(<LoginComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

works fine. But the router simply renders nothing at all.

I use

```
browserify -g reactify app.jsx > bundle.js
```

to transform and bundle my components and the dependencies, consequently thats my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The React Router version is 4.0.0

Last thing to say is that I serve the folder of the index.html and app.jsx file via express:

```
var express = Express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder on default
express.use(Express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337,
    httpServer = require('http').createServer(express);

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

ANY ideas why nothing is rendered? - I am kind of desperate

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to create a wildcard route `URL` in a backend server that takes you back to where reload happens, as follows:

```
express.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(Path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Correct import in `index.html`, as:

```
var browserHistory = require ('react-router').browserHistory;
```

Comment: I tried it - the result is the same: index.html is send properly but bundle.js renders nothing.

Comment: @JSthoff any error on browser console? anyway, check my updated answer.

Comment: I checked the console and inserted some logs - I have no clue why but i looks like "require ('react-router').browserHistory;"  returns undefined.

Comment: which version of `react-router` you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it myself - react-router of npm doesnt got the the history object so i switched to react-router-dom:

```
var Router = require('react-router-dom').HashRouter;
var Route = require('react-router-dom').Route;
var Link = require('react-router-dom').Link;
```

and everything works as usual:

```
<Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/login">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/signup">Topics</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/home">home</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={LandingComponent}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignupComponent}/>
        <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

note: Hashrouter enables reload when serving the index file via express.use